# My jquery menu focus function is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm sorry but I just started to learn jquery and Im struggling with a most basic thing
jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ufvakggn/

Here is my function :

```
var active = $('nav ul li');

active.focus(function() {
    $(this).children('ul').toggleClass('active');
})
```

basically I want to navigate with tab through my menu. I thought the best way to do this is to use a toggleclass on children element when a parent element has focus. But I can't make this work

update : actually I made some progress with

```
var active = $('.has-sub a');

active.focus(function() {
    $('nav ul ul').toggleClass('active');
})
```

still trying to find a way to tab through every element and not activating all submenus when I focus something

Answer (score 0):

You want to target the specific `<ul>` that is a `sibling` of the target `<a>`

```
$('.has-sub a').on('focus blur', function() {
    $(this).siblings('ul').toggleClass('active');
});
```

Within an event handler `this` is the element within the selector that the event occurred on. From that element you can use whatever traverses you need to target other specific elements

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ufvakggn/2/)**</kbd>

Comment: thanks it worked, I added those lines

$('a').on('focus blur', function () {
    $(this).parents('ul').toggleClass('active');
}) , so when I focus a subitem, the menu stays active.  But as I can see, the css is quite messed up compared to the hover version

Comment: just combine the hover and active rules into one. rules can have as many comma separated selectors as you want

Comment: humm yeah so I should list `.active li` in the hover styling rules then, thanks

Comment: I dont know if you're still there but I noticed a problem, this fonction gives the "active" class also to the parent ul (first level ul)! and not only to the ul sibling with <a> unfortunately. still trying to find the right selector to avoid this problem

Comment: siblings should be exactly what you want to open... just realizing that it will collapse though on blur when you try to move into the submenu. Try using blur on the parent li

Comment: i figured the problem, I just had to create a ".focused" class with jquery. here is the result with styling : http://jsfiddle.net/ufvakggn/4/. Now I need to sort tabbing order I guess, but thats with html!